# Python Old print statement

Tags: python

I just got Syntax error on 'print' with Python 3, and by searching I found that in the newer python version print statement is replaced with print function (http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function).

So what was 'print' before python 3? And how it was implemented? Is it possible to create statement like old 'print' which act like functions?

Comment: `print` was a statement in Python 2.7, not a function.

Comment: Python2: `print foo`.  Python3: `print (foo)`.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, it was a statement. Statements are handled at the interpreter level, because each one has their own rules in the parsing tree; so it's very unlikely that you can add your own statements to the language (without patching the interpreter and compiler code), Python is not designed to be **that** extensible.

There are still some provisions to make that kind of hacks, you could take a look on the way the `from future import ...` works:

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert python 2 code to python 3, you could use 2to3 script.
see http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_